# Changing the selection of RadioButtons in a GroupBox within a DataRepeater will change the selection of other RadioButtons

Tags: vb.net, radio-button, groupbox, datarepeater

I have a DataRepeater in which I have a Label (LabelID) and a GroupBox which contains RadioButtons. I am binding the Labels to a column from a DataTable and what I wish to do is to give the user the chance to select one of the Radio Buttons within each cell of DataRepeater and then upon progress I wish to read the user's selection for each cell. The problem is that when the user starts selecting the radio buttons and scrolls down to select radio buttons for other cells within the DataRepeater, the previous selections change or even the ones that user has not selected yet get selected. I have no idea why this is happening.

Here is the code for what I have done:

```
LabelID.DataBindings.Clear()
LabelID.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", SomeDataTable, "SomeID"))
myDataRepeater.DataSource = SomeDataTable
```

I added the GroupBox which contains the RadioButtons in the Visual Studio drag and drop framework.

I tried the following binding as something that I thought might solve the problem, but it did not.

```
GroupBoxSelection.DataBindings.Clear()
GroupBoxSelection.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Tag", SomeDataTable, "SomeID"))
```

I know it has something to do with scrolling the DataRepeater up and down. Because I increased the size of the DataRepeater to get rid of the ScrollBar and this strange behavior won't happen anymore. I cannot keep the DataRepeater that big so I would like to find another solution.

Any help will be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the `DataRepeater` works exactly but I wouldn't be surprised if it reused controls to increase performance. If so then your controls may be retaining their values as they are moved.  What you might try is creating a user control to contain the `RadioButtons` and expose a single property that you can then bind.  If an instance gets reused then the binding should update correctly as it does for the other controls.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but the exact same problem persists. :(